# C# How to continuously move sprite until they collide

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue moving the player continuously in one direction after they click an arrow key until they hit a sprite with the 'Ground' tag, then they would come to a complete stop and would be able to go another direction again. I've tried using variables to check if the player was moving / if they've collided yet but I can't seem to get it to work.

The code below is how the player moves right now, it just goes in the direction of the arrow key that is being held down. (my player is a sprite)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float vertical;
    private float speed = 8f;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bool isGrounded = IsGrounded();

        // Calculate movement based on input direction (horizontal and vertical).
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, vertical * speed);

        // If there's horizontal input and no vertical input, move horizontally only.
        if (Mathf.Abs(horizontal) > 0f && Mathf.Abs(vertical) == 0f)
        {
            movement.y = 0f;
        }
        // If there's vertical input and no horizontal input, move vertically only.
        else if (Mathf.Abs(vertical) > 0f && Mathf.Abs(horizontal) == 0f)
        {
            movement.x = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            // If both horizontal and vertical inputs are present, don't move.
            movement.x = 0f;
            movement.y = 0f;
        }

        rb.velocity = movement;
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a coroutine, since your problem has very distinct multi frame phases. It's going to look a bit esoteric.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float vertical;
    private float speed = 8f;
    private Vector2 movement;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(HandleMove());
    }

    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        movement = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical) * speed;
    }

    IEnumerator HandleMove()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //wait until player enters grounded sprite
            while (IsGrounded() == false)
            {
                yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
            }
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;//stops
            Debug.Log("entered ground Sprite");

            //wait for valid input
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => ValidInput());
            rb.velocity = movement;
            Debug.Log("velocity set");

            //wait until player exits grounded sprite
            while (IsGrounded() == true)
            {
                yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
            }
            Debug.Log("exited ground Sprite");
        }
    }

    private bool ValidInput()
    {
        //if both axis are greater than zero (two directions selected) 
        //or both axis are zero (no direction selected) the input is invalid
        if (vertical != 0f && horizontal != 0f || vertical == 0f && horizontal == 0f)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //if the input is valid the axis of movement are already correct
        //no need to zero them
        return true;
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }
}
```

Obviously the ground sprites need to be the **layer** that is selected in `groundLayer` and have a Collider2D component (box collider for example) attached. The player needs to have a Rigidbody2D and has to start on a ground sprite.

The physics system is quite fickle, so I'd also recommend setting the Rigidbody to a `Continious` `Collision Detection`. In general the system might fail if you use high speeds, small colliders or are very far away from the world origin. If you somehow miss the next sprite you're out of luck and will continue moving in that direction indefinitely.